# How to pause a RabbitMQ consumer using Rabbus?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, rabbus

I've got a send/receive implementation using [Rabbus](https://github.com/derickbailey/rabbus) (a RabbitMQ abstraction using Wascally).

Due to resource limitations I can only consume a given number of jobs during a fixed time period. Hence, I need to pause/halt the consumer/receiver for a while and then resume. Is there a way to use `basic.cancel` from Rabbus, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

there is a .stop() method for your consumer that is not documented. i'll have to run a test to see if you can stop and restart a consumer without issues... i think so, but i've never really tested that as i've not needed to do that. i'll let you know what i find

Comment: Thanks Derick, you're doing an awesome job with Rabbus!